# Spring custom editor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, property-editor

I've added custom property editor to spring handler. And it works with one of the property on jspx page, but not the others, for it, it just outputs toString of Money class.

```
public void initBinder(final HttpServletRequest request, final ServletRequestDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Money.class, new MoneyPropertyEditor());
}
```

And in jspx property with Money type is referenced as:

```
<cat:input type="text" uiid="amount" bindpath="form.pack.amount"/>€
```

Money property editor looks like

```
public String getAsText() {
        String textValue = null;

        if (this.getValue() != null) {
            Money money = (Money) this.getValue();

            System.out.println("getAsText money: " + money);

            textValue = String.valueOf(money.getAmount());

            System.out.println("textValue: " + textValue);
        }

        return textValue;
    }
```

System out is:

```
getAsText money: Money:  Amount: 0.7, AsCents: 70
textValue: 0.7
```

So - property editor works and is invoked. But input is still holds toString respresentation: `money: Money:  Amount: 0.7, AsCents: 70` and not `0.7`

What else should be configured so that output custom property editor will be used?

Comment: Do you have other fields of type `Money` on the object you are attempting to databind?

Comment: Yes, they are referenced pretty much in the same manner `<cat:input type="text"
                       bindpath="form.pack.cyclicUsage.secondCycleFee"
                       /> €</td>`

Answer (score 0):

Question is resolved! Actually, in this case PropertyEditor worked just fine, field was later modified by external js.